# CheckBox IsChecked & IsMouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

i've recently made some control designs and wanted to use them, but i see there is a problem. Generally the Checkbox has 4 Images:

1. When normal state
2. When Mouse over
3. When it's checked
4. And when it's checked AND mouse over

But the 4. State doesnt exist, i show u how i did so far:

```
        <ControlTemplate  x:Key="ModernCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="_Image" Source="CheckBox_Normal.png" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
            <ContentControl Content="CheckBox"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="CheckBox.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="_Image" Property="Source" Value="CheckBox_NormalHover.png"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="_Image" Property="Source" Value="CheckBox_Checked.png"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="CheckBox.??" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="_Image" Property="Source" Value="CheckBox_CheckedHover.png"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

My Template works well so far, but as u can see i found no way for the last State, so i ask here for help!

kind regards,

Jake

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to use a [MultiTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger.aspx) in order to react to your state #4

e.g.

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="_Image" Property="Source" Value="CheckBox_CheckedHover.png"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MultiTrigger to test multiple property values:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Property="CheckBox.IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
      <Condition Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="_Image" Property="Source" Value="CheckBox_CheckedHover.png"/>     
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just change the `StaticResource` for `OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph` and the `StaticResource` for `OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph`